# What Options Are There To Protect Database Passwords In Corda?

Tags: corda

The Corda database password is stored in the node.conf in plain text by default:

https://docs.corda.net/head/node-database.html

What options are available to avoid this?

e.g. can you use jasypt or store the value in an environment variable or a cloud vault system?

Are there samples/examples available?

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to override node.conf settings using Environment variables or JVM arguments, see here for more info: https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html#overriding-values-from-node-conf

The Enterprise version of Corda also ships with a configuration obfuscator tool which can be used to encrypt settings: https://docs.corda.r3.com/tools-config-obfuscator.html